# Unable to consume a webservice exposed using jboss from android using ksoap

Tags: java, android, web-services, jboss

I am new to android and ws.I have a jboss server with in which I have exposed some web services using annotations. I am using ksoap2 library to consume that web service  but it is throwing RunTimeException : can not serialize error.

WSDL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="AccountOperationService" targetNamespace="http://provider.account.com/Version1" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://provider.account.com/Version1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://provider.account.com/Version1" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://provider.account.com/Version1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="CreateException" type="tns:CreateException"/>
   <xs:element name="getAccountDetail" type="tns:getAccountDetail"/>
   <xs:complexType name="init">
    <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="initResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CreateException">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="getAccountDetail">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arguments" type="tns:getAccountDetailRequestVO"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="getAccountDetailRequestVO">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="accountNumber" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="balanceInfoRequired" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="getAccountDetailResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:accountDetailResponseVO"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="accountDetailResponseVO">
    <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:extension base="tns:integrationBaseResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="accountVOs" nillable="true" type="tns:accountResponseVO"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="accountResponseVO">
    <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:extension base="tns:integrationBaseResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="accountNumber" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name="AccountOperation_getAccountDetail">
  <part element="tns:getAccountDetail" name="getAccountDetail"/>
 </message>

  <operation name="getAccountDetail" parameterOrder="getAccountDetail">
   <input message="tns:AccountOperation_getAccountDetail"/>
   <output message="tns:AccountOperation_getAccountDetailResponse"/>
  </operation>

 </portType>
 <binding name="AccountOperation" type="tns:AccountOperation">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

  <operation name="getAccountDetail">
   <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </output>
  </operation>

 </binding>
 <service name="AccountOperationService">
  <port binding="tns:AccountOperationBinding" name="AccountOperationPort">
   <soap:address location="http://10.110.1.98:8080/account/AccountOperationsWebService/AccountOperationService/AccountOperation"/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

Java Code :

```
    String METHOD_NAME = "getAccountDetail";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://provider.account.com/Version1";
    String URL = "http://10.110.1.98:8080/account/AccountOperationsWebService/AccountOperationService/AccountOperation?wsdl";
    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+ METHOD_NAME;
    String response = null;

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);    

    try
    {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo p1 = new PropertyInfo();
        p1.setName("accountNumber");
        p1.setType(String.class);
        p1.setValue("ACCM561680");
        request.addProperty("arguments",p1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        try
        {
            SoapObject responsePM = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            response = responsePM.toString();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "Error occured";
        }
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (Exception aE)
    {
        System.out.println(aE.toString());
        aE.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: accountNumber : ACCM561680
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: accountNumber : ACCM561680
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:664)
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:649)
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:604)
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:582)
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:658)
    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:564)
    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:205)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:111)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:121)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
    at MyBackgroundTask_Billing2.doInBackground(MyBackgroundTask_Billing2.java:33)
    at MyBackgroundTask_Billing2.main(MyBackgroundTask_Billing2.java:55)
```

Thanks in advance